# highcharts display percentage complete

Tags: php, yii, highcharts, bar-chart

I am trying to create a graph in php using highcharts. i want to make a bar graph display project startdate - endate showing percent complete. I have all 3 of these values coming from database. 4th value i want to display if possible on the graph is using current date if the project is lacking behind schedule by shading in the bar.

The following is what I have

```
var date = new Date();
```

//console.log(date.getFullYear() + " " +  (date.getMonth()+1) + " " + date.getDay() );

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Snow depth in the Vikjafjellet mountain, Norway'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'An example of irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Percent %'
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var start = new Date(2013,5,11),
             end = new Date(2013,11,11),
            today = new Date();
                return  Math.round(100-((end - start) * 100 ) / today) + '%' ;//'<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' m';
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Fastnet OffshWest Shetland',
        // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
        // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
        // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2013,  5, 11), 0   ],
            [Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), (date.getMonth()+1), date.getDay()), 30 ],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 11, 11), 100 ]
        ]
    }]
});
```

[image]

I have been modifying the line graph. I want to turn this into a bar chart showing each project with a start date end date. and current completed percent. I also want to calculated and display the predicted percentage that should be complete using current date.

Comment: What is your question? What is the current output and what is the expected one?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide an example image of what you want the chart to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need bar chart, with actual percent progress on yAxis, and start - end date on xAxis, if yes, here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/hbEsj/

Use columnrange chart, which allows you to pass data as: `[value, timestamp1, timestamp2]`:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: -10,
        max : 110,
        tickInterval: 25,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        reversed: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 20
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: [
            [36, Date.UTC(2013,0,1),Date.UTC(2013,0,13)]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Project 2',
        data: [
            [66, Date.UTC(2013,0,1),Date.UTC(2013,0,10)]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Projec 3',
        data: [
            [100, Date.UTC(2013,0,1),Date.UTC(2013,0,3)]
        ]
    }]

});
```

However, I don't understand part with predicted and calculated value - Highcharts is a library to display data, not to predict anything.